# Cronbach Alpha VS Composite Reliability: a big difference?

Tags: factor-analysis, reliability, cronbachs-alpha, composite

I've read elsewhere that Alpha is probably a low-bound estimate of realibility if the tau equivalence is violated (which is often is). An alternative was proposed which is the composite reliability. Let's say that my Cronbach Alpha produced a reliability (or internal consistency) of 0.62. However and using factor loadings ([on this calculator](http://www.thestatisticalmind.com/calculators/comprel/composite_reliability.htm)) to calculate CR, my CR returned around 0.73. Could that much of a difference really exists? If so, can I safely proceed with my analysis and conclude that my construct or factor is generally reliable?

Comment: Far from a conclusive answer, but see the second comment to [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103723/what-is-the-relationship-between-scale-reliability-measures-cronbachs-alpha-et). As far as I can see, composite reliability is calculated using factor loadings. If Cronbach's alpha and factor loadings are qualitatively different then it doesn't seem surprising that Cronbach's alpha and composite reliability could differ markedly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you think that one can be on the safe side if one proceeds with a Cronbach of 0.63 but with CR of 0.77? (Results are robust and significance is still found)

Comment: You probably would need to acknowledge that the reliability of your measurements may not be very good.

Comment: That would definitely be done. However and if significant results are to still be found, can one conclude that despite the weak reliability (since weaker ones increase error and decrease statistical power), measurements were still found to be robust. Am I correct if I write something like this?

Comment: I'm not sure. Intuitively, it seems like results obtained using an unreliable instrument could be spurious. This seems like a whole other question in itself.

Comment: But one has to remember that a lower alpha increases the error margin and decreases the correlation power/bound and so, naturally, if an alpha of 0.3 is used, p would not be significant because of this alpha but if alpha of 0.6 is used and significance is found, one can conclude that, with even a higher alpha, a higher relationship/significance/correlation would have been found.